# Set the data from api to be the inital state of editorState for draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm creating a richtexteditor component using draft.js that will display data from my api. But I cant find a way to diplay this to my Editor using draft.js. Can someone explain me why? I tried to create a var with the same data from my api and Its working fine.

**sample data from api**

[image]

`"<p>Hello world this is <strong>me<strong></p>"`

**screenshot of the data from mongoDB**

[image]

```
const ViewTaskComment = ({ comment }) => {
  const contentBlocks = convertFromHTML(comment);

  const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    contentBlocks.contentBlocks,
    contentBlocks.entityMap
  );

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
  );

  const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
  };

  return (
    <div className='comment-container p-2 border rounded-md'>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        wrapperClassName='wrapper-class'
        editorClassName='editor-class'
        toolbarClassName='toolbar-class'
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewTaskComment;
```

Comment: Try to change `onEditorStateChange` to `onChange`. I created a sandbox with working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-bassi-jhg0j?file=/src/ViewTaskComment.jsx

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried to change the oneditorStateChant to onChange but there's a error. Also the data from API not showing up. I also tried to create a static data like what you and I don't have any issue. But when I tried to pass the data coming from API is not working. The data coming from my database using mongodb

Comment: So, `comment` is an object, not a string? Make sure that you pass a string to `convertFromHTML()`. Also, what version of draft-js are you using?

Comment: Comment is a data coming from the Backend that being save as a string. You can see on the top that I included the screenshot of the data coming from the backend. If I'm not mistaken also check it by console.log(typeOf comment) the result is string. The version is 0.11.7.